# How to draw and rotate square inside center of other square?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, graphics, graphics2d

I need to draw some squares inside other square but I don't know how to rotate my squares by center of them and make them smaller? 
Here is a picture how it should looks like at the end:

[image]

Now I have some code which draw squares which make circle.

```
class MySquare  extends JComponent {
public void paint(Graphics g) {

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {

        g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(45 - (i * 10)), 100, 100);

        // Difrent colors:
        if (i % 2 == 0)
            g2d.setColor(Color.black);
        else
            g2d.setColor(Color.green);
        g2d.fillRect(50, 50, 100, 100);

    }
    }
}

public class DrawRect {
  public static void main(String[] a) {
    JFrame window = new JFrame();
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setBounds(30, 30, 800, 800);
    window.getContentPane().add(new MySquare());
    window.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could first draw your figure around the origin (that's easy) and then translate:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        frame.add(new JPanel() {

            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

                double alpha = Math.toRadians(5);
                double factor = 1 / (Math.sin(alpha) + Math.cos(alpha));
                double size = 200;

                g2d.translate(size, size);

                for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                    g2d.setColor(i % 2 == 0 ? Color.black : Color.green);

                    int intSize = (int) Math.round(size);

                    g2d.fillRect(-intSize / 2, -intSize / 2, intSize, intSize);

                    size = size * factor;

                    g2d.rotate(alpha);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I run this code but squares are not even in one place, so I'm not sure if I want that.

Comment: custom painting for Swing components should be done in paintComponent (vs. paint) - to @user2245026 as well

Comment: @user2245026 you're right, space transformations are always confusing. I should have done the translate before the rotate. Updated the code and made an SSCCE to show the concept.

Comment: @Heuster Just one more question. It works just great, but could you tell me why  `double factor = 1 / (Math.sin(alpha) + Math.cos(alpha))` looks like that ?

Comment: @user2245026 Yeah, I'll try to explain based on the picture above. Look at the biggest black and green square. Let's say the black square has side length `N` and the green one `X`. The bottom of the black square is equal to the sum of the 2 black triangles. The left black triangle has side length `X sin(alpha)` and the right one `X cos(alpha)`. Hence, `N = X (sin(alpha) + cos(alpha))` and `X = N / (sin(alpha) + cos(alpha))`. This pattern repeats for every square.

Comment: What you mean by: _The bottom of the black square is equal to the sum of the 2 black triangles._ I don't get it what is sum of 2 black triangels? Their sides ?

Comment: @user2245026 yes, I meant the length of their sides, but I was limited by the amount of characters ;-)